# Get public variable from another class

Tags: c#, variables, xamarin.forms

I have a class where there's a public static variable that I want to access from another class. Here's the class :
In GlobalVariable.cs

```
public class GlobalVariable
{
    public static int MoisVS = 3;
}
```

And I want to access to "MoisVS" from another class. Here's the class :
In ArretPage.cs

```
var globalvariable = new ProjetTN.Class.GlobalVariable();
globalvariable.MoisVS;  //<--- Make something like that.
```

I know it's possible in a WinForm app but is that possible in a Xamarin.forms app ?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried and it didn't work that's why I asked this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your `MoisVS` as static so you can't access it from an instance variable. Accessing static members of a class you're using the class name itself. So for example accessing your `MoisVS` will look like:

```
GlobalVariable.MoisVS
```

If you want to accesss it as an instance property you have to change your class to:

```
public class GlobalVariable
{
    public int MoisVS = 3;
}
```

If there are only static or const values in your class. You can also decide to make your whole class static

```
public static class GlobalVariable
{
    public static int MoisVS = 3;
    public const string MyString = "";
}
```

this will prevent you from using the new keyword to create an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I will break this into steps.

1) File -> New File -> General -> Choose Empty Class -> Name it (e.g.UICONTROL_NAMES)

2) Add the following: (Sample code)

```
using System;

namespace iOSControls.HelperClass
{
    public static class UICONTROL_NAMES
    {
        public const string textField = "Text Fields";
        public const string inputTextField = "Input types - TextFields";
        public const string button = "Buttons";
        public const string label = "Label";
}
```

**Have a note:**

```
UICONTROL_NAMES class is inside a folder group called HelperClass and iOSControls is the project name.
```

3) On your ViewController.cs, add namespace directive.

```
using iOSControls.HelperClass;
using Foundation;
```

4) Access const strings in UICONTROL NAMES:

```
string controlName = UICONTROL_NAMES.textField;
```